# Select a single maximum or minimum value in entire table of oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

select maximum value from different columns of the table

For example, Table

```
 A  B  C
 -------
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

Result would be like

```
Max
9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the values are never `NULL`, I would simply do:

```
select max(greatest(a, b, c))
from t;
```

You could also phrase this as:

```
select greatest(max(a), max(b), max(c))
from t;
```

This version is more resilient to `NULL` values.  It will work with `NULL`s unless *all* values for a column are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select greatest(max(a), max(b), max(c))
  from your_table;
```

Or:

```
select max(x)
  from (select max(a) as x from your_table union all
        select max(b) from your_table union all
        select max(c) from your_table union all
  )
```

Comment: It is also not working in case of null values. Max() returns null if all rows has null value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, which uses `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions, enclosed into `MAX` and `MIN` aggregates:

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c) as
  2    (select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 4, 5, 6 from dual union all
  4     select 7, 8, 9 from dual
  5    )
  6  select max(greatest(a, b, c)) max_result,
  7         min(least(a, b, c)) min_result
  8  from test;

MAX_RESULT MIN_RESULT
---------- ----------
         9          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 select max(value) as Max from (
 select max(A) as value from example
 union 
 select max(B) as value from example 
 union
 select max(C) as value from example ) as tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will also handle the NULL values present in the column.

```
WITH tempData (a, b, c) AS (SELECT NULL, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 8, NULL FROM DUAL)
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(a), MAX(b), MAX(c)) AS maxval, LEAST(MIN(a), MIN(b), MIN(c)) AS minval FROM tempData;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
select greatest(NVL(c1, 0),NVL(c2, 0),NVL(c3, 0), NVL(c4, 0)) from T
```